Is yGuard obfusction backward compatibility still supported with recent versions of yGuard
I used to obfuscate Java 8 builds with yGuard 2.7.1. Backward compatibility was working fine.
Backward compatibility is broken with yGuard 4.1.0 (and other recent versions) for my Java 8 and Java 17 builds.
I'm trying to get backward compatibility for Java 17 code obfuscation.
Consecutive obfuscation runs for yGuard 4.1.0 and Java 17 end up in different mappings for the same class. It does not affect all the classes though. The code is not changed between the obfuscation runs.

I’m surprised to hear that you ever got the same mapping for consecutive runs. If the mapping is always the same, it is effectively reversible. Which defeats the entire purpose of obfuscation. If you want a stable mapping, you must specify the mapping explicitly. This has nothing to do with compatibility.

"If the mapping is always the same, it is effectively reversible." - Only if you know the input API and the yGuard configuration and you usually don't.

@tom314 Can you share your yGuard configuration?

@ThomasBehr you’d only need to know the yGuard settings affecting the mapping and being able to guess the input by brute force is what makes the scenario reversible. It doesn’t matter how likely or unlikely the attack is, obfuscation tools simply avoid it by not having reproducible mappings.

@Holger Obfuscation is not a one-to-one function. You are not "able to guess the input by brute force" - even if you know the yGuard settings (which you don't). Maybe some obfuscation tools randomize their mappings, yGuard does not, though (at least not intentionally). I would know, I am the current maintainer of yGuard.

@ThomasBehr since yGuard has no stable mapping function, in fact, the output name choice does not even depend on the input name, there is no need for an additional randomization. It’s also pointless to discuss which options I would need to know to exploit the stable mapping function that doesn’t exist. If you are the current maintainer of yGuard, you can tell whether any effort has been spent on implementing a stable mapping. To my knowledge, none.

You can use yGuard's map element to specify mappings from a previous obfuscation run to enforce stable obfuscation.
